# Need Help Removing Nested INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, nested, inner-join

I have the following `INNER JOIN` statement in a SQL query that I'd like to change so there is no nested `INNER JOIN` statements.  I believe this to be causing a Cartesian Product because it is taking 20+ minutes to return a couple thousand rows of results.  Can someone help me figure out how to remove the nesting?

```
SELECT        
TECH_INCDT_V.INCDT_NUM_I AS [Incident Number], 
TECH_INCDT_V.ASGN_TO_USER_I AS [Incident Assigned User ID], 
SVY_RESP_V_3.RESP_VAL_Q AS [Survey Response], 
SVY_QUES_V_3.QUES_T AS [Survey Question]


FROM supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.SVY_QUES_V AS SVY_QUES_V_7 
INNER JOIN supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.SVY_RESP_V AS SVY_RESP_V_7 ON SVY_QUES_V_7.SVY_QUES_I = SVY_RESP_V_7.SVY_QUES_I 

-->START INNER JOIN "A"
INNER JOIN supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.TECH_INCDT_V

    -->These are NESTED within the INNER JOIN "A" in the previous line
    INNER JOIN supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.PERS_V ON TECH_INCDT_V.CRTE_USER_I = PERS_V.PERS_LAN_I 
    INNER JOIN supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.SVY_TASK_V ON TECH_INCDT_V.INCDT_NUM_I = SVY_TASK_V.INCDT_NUM_I 
    INNER JOIN supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.SVY_INSTC_V ON SVY_TASK_V.SVY_INSTC_I = SVY_INSTC_V.SVY_INSTC_I 
    INNER JOIN supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.SVY_RESP_V ON SVY_INSTC_V.SVY_INSTC_I = SVY_RESP_V.SVY_INSTC_I 
    INNER JOIN supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.SVY_QUES_V ON SVY_RESP_V.SVY_QUES_I = SVY_QUES_V.SVY_QUES_I 
    INNER JOIN supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.SVY_TASK_V AS SVY_TASK_V_3 ON TECH_INCDT_V.INCDT_NUM_I = SVY_TASK_V_3.INCDT_NUM_I AND SVY_INSTC_V.SVY_INSTC_I = SVY_TASK_V_3.SVY_INSTC_I 
    INNER JOIN supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.SVY_RESP_V AS SVY_RESP_V_3 ON SVY_INSTC_V.SVY_INSTC_I = SVY_RESP_V_3.SVY_INSTC_I 
    INNER JOIN supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.SVY_QUES_V AS SVY_QUES_V_3 ON SVY_RESP_V_3.SVY_QUES_I = SVY_QUES_V_3.SVY_QUES_I 
    INNER JOIN supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.SVY_TASK_V AS SVY_TASK_V_7 ON TECH_INCDT_V.INCDT_NUM_I = SVY_TASK_V_7.INCDT_NUM_I AND SVY_INSTC_V.SVY_INSTC_I = SVY_TASK_V_7.SVY_INSTC_I 
    -->Nesting ends here

-->END INNER JOIN "A"
ON SVY_RESP_V_7.SVY_INSTC_I = SVY_INSTC_V.SVY_INSTC_I 

INNER JOIN supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.PERS_V AS PERS_V_2 ON SVY_INSTC_V.CMPL_BY_USER_I = PERS_V_2.PERS_LAN_I 
LEFT OUTER JOIN supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.ACCT_DATE_DIM AS ACCT_DATE_DIM_OPEN ON CONVERT(varchar(8), TECH_INCDT_V.CRTE_TS, 112) = ACCT_DATE_DIM_OPEN.GREG_D 
LEFT OUTER JOIN supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.ACCT_DATE_DIM AS ACCT_DATE_DIM_SVY ON CONVERT(varchar(8), SVY_INSTC_V.CMPL_TS, 112) = ACCT_DATE_DIM_SVY.GREG_D

WHERE        
(SVY_QUES_V.SVY_QUES_I IS NOT NULL) AND 
(TECH_INCDT_V.CRTE_WKGRP_N LIKE '%FAKE%' OR TECH_INCDT_V.CRTE_WKGRP_N IS NULL)

GROUP BY 
TECH_INCDT_V.INCDT_NUM_I,
TECH_INCDT_V.ASGN_TO_USER_I, 
SVY_RESP_V_3.RESP_VAL_Q, 
SVY_QUES_V_3.QUES_T, 
SVY_QUES_V_3.SVY_QUES_I,
TECH_INCDT_V.CRTE_TS
```

**I'm trying to get rid of the nested INNER JOIN statements between here:**

```
INNER JOIN supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.TECH_INCDT_V
```

**and here:**

```
ON SVY_RESP_V_7.SVY_INSTC_I = SVY_INSTC_V.SVY_INSTC_I
```

Comment: Please post the complete SQL

Comment: You're missing the ON statement in front of `INNER JOIN supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.TECH_INCDT_V`. This is why you're getting a cartesian product. You need to join the tables in the correct way or order. Without knowing your DB schema, it is not possible to figure out how the joins must happen.

Comment: Nothing is missing.   The query runs fine as is.

Comment: I indented the INNNER JOIN statements that are nested so it's easier to see that nothing is missing.  The indented INNER JOIN statements are the ones I am trying to move outside of their containing INNER JOIN statement.

Comment: Downvoted because you couldn't answer the question?

Comment: I don't see how the query is "nested". If you inner join a table without specify a "on" clause, you will get a product of the table (like a full join). Just because query runs fine does not mean it is correct. You need to add an "on" clause to the inner join where it is missing.

Comment: Line 11 starts an INNER JOIN, line 23 has the ON clause, everything in between is nested inner joins.  The surrounding inner join will fail without the nested inner join statements.

Answer (score 1):

There are no 'nested' `joins` (whatever that may mean), just incomplete `joins`. Your `inner join` 'A' does NOT have an `ON` clause. The `ON` clause you mention in your comments has no relation to the table in the join. You ARE `joining` supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.PERS_V `on` the table in join 'A' (as well as a couple of others), but you are not `joining` supt_oper_anls_dw.dbo.TECH_INCDT_V to anything else. As @navigator said, you need to add an `ON` clause, just after join "A" and before your so-called 'nested' joins. What that `ON` clause should be is impossible to say with the information provided.

Also, what is your RDBMS?

Comment: If I remove 'ON SVY_RESP_V_7.SVY_INSTC_I = SVY_INSTC_V.SVY_INSTC_I ', the query gives errors and no longer runs.  If I move it ANYWHERE, the query gives errors and no longer runs.  If I delete it, the query gives errors and no longer runs.  It most certainly being used, so maybe you can explain how it is being used and why it fails when it is moved or deleted?  Also, I don't know what "RDBMS" means... I've only been using SQL for about 2 years and I definitely cannot share anything about our tables beyond what you can infer from this query.  This is not my query, it was handed to me at work...

Comment: RDMS is your Database Management System, so Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL etc. You should add an ON clause for your INNER JOIN A, and change your last ON clause to "AND SVY_RESP_V_7.SVY_INSTC_I = SVY_INSTC_V.SVY_INSTC_I". I can't help you with the ON clause you should make, I would need much more information about the table structure. You should probably ask around if you don't know either. I'm surprised this query even runs, let alone returns a result close to what you want, the whole join syntax is logically incorrect as it is.

Comment: I agree about this query being incorrect and maybe I should've mentioned it was handed to me this way in my original post so I wouldn't get downvoted... I'm just trying to clean up someone else's mess here...

Comment: It doesn't matter, we've all been there, I suppose, getting handed bad code. I think the reason you got downvoted, tough, is your use of the term "nested join". There is no such thing, and people get thrown off when terms are used like that. Have you been able to fix it yet?

Comment: Not fixed and I doubt it ever will be... The effort is just not worth the reward here. If the query is getting us the results we want "it's not broken". They don't want to pay me to keep messing with it.